# Input list within a Manipulate (Setter)

Tags: manipulate, interface

I would like to make an interactive "to do" list with a `SetterBar` where I can click on the Chapter, and get a list of tasks I can add to or delete within the associated chapter.

Here is the skeleton code.  I click on whichever chapter I want to update.

```
Manipulate[
 "Place editable 'to do' list for chosen chapter here",
 {Chapter, {"Preface", "1", "2", "3", "Appendix"},
  ControlType -> Setter}]
```

But how do I make an editable list (such as a bullet list) within the Manipulate window such that edits are stored appropriately for each chapter?

Answer (score 3):

A quick-and-dirty way using `TabView` (sorry no bullets:):

```
TabView[Thread[(Style[#, ShowStringCharacters -> False] & /@
      {"Preface", "1", "2", "3",  "Appendix"}) -> 
   Table[Pane[Grid[{{Placeholder[]}}, Alignment -> Left], ImageSize -> {300, 300}], {5}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful (+1)... but I was hoping for the manipulate framework.